# How to deal with invalid characters in a WS output when using CXF?

Tags: java, xml, spring, cxf

I'm using Spring, CXF and Hibernate to build a WebService that perform search queries on a foreign database that I have read-only access.

The problem is that some entries in the database have strange characters (0x2) in text fields, and it seems that CXF or the library (Aegis?) that it uses to process/serialize the objects returned from the Hibernate session can't deal with it:

```
org.apache.cxf.aegis.DatabindingException: Error writing document.. Nested exception is com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid white space character (0x2) in text to output (in xml 1.1, could output as a character entity)
```

How do I get around that?
Ideally, I could just remove those characters, since they don't matter for my output...
Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
/**
* From xml spec valid chars:<br>
* #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]<br>
* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF.<br>
* @param text The String to clean
* @param replacement The string to be substituted for each match
* @return The resulting String
*/
public static String CleanInvalidXmlChars(String text, String replacement) {
    String re = "[^\u0009\r\n\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]";
    return text.replaceAll(re, replacement);
}
```

source: http://www.theplancollection.com/house-plan-related-articles/hexadecimal-value-invalid-characterheplancollection.com/house-plan-related-articles/hexadecimal-value-invalid-character

Comment: Isn't this wrong? I mean, the regexp (escaped for java) should be: "[^\\x09\\x0A\\x0D\\x20-\\xD7FF\\xE000-\\xFFFD\\x10000-\\x10FFFF]"

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure this answers your question, but here is what I found.

Here is the class that throws the exception:
http://svn.codehaus.org/woodstox/wstx/trunk/src/java/com/ctc/wstx/api/InvalidCharHandler.java

Seems like there is a discussion on the issue here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.cxf.user/4373

**Maybe this might can you:**
You can also set a "disable.outputstream.optimization" property on the 
endpoint/bus to true to have it disable the direct writing to the outputstream 
and always go through the XMLStreamWriter.  Should accomplish the same thing 
without the overhead of having the SAAJModel created.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks, man! I've actually read that discussion already before posting this question. :) From Dan Kulp's answer, I understood maybe I could write a wrapper for XMLStreamWriter to replace the characters, I'm trying to figure out how to do that...

Comment: If I understand this correctly this is just a whitespace? Could you remove/replace it in your code before writing it to xml?

Comment: To do that in my own code it would require putting all the database objects into memory to process them, before sending the response. I don't want to do that just because of a small percentage of problematic data. I need to put the code to remove the chars just before CXF's data binding writes the object to the output... I've been reading CXF's docs to see how to go about that.

Comment: I see. If you figure this out, please post it here. I would be interested in your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, Jarle! It turns out I was wrong: the database objects were already loaded into memory! I was needlessly worried. So I just processed a result list them before returning. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, good to hear everything worked out :)

Comment: I believe the right url to InvalidCharHandler.java is https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ctc/wstx/api/InvalidCharHandler.java nowadays, as codehaus has been dead for quite for some time. Yes, I know this answer is old but let's keep the URLs up to date ;)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the desired behaviour and avoid exceptions being thrown, you'll have to extend the default Woodstoks factory `com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory` with your own's, that's supposed only to overwrite the property `com.ctc.wstx.outputInvalidCharHandler` with an instance of `com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler.ReplacingHandler`. This handler takes as constructor argument the replacement char to the invalid ones. With your instance in hand, create a file named `META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory` and place inside it only the complete name of your implementation (make sure it'll be placed inside the META-INF/services directory in the resulting jar).

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421275/axis2-error-invalid-white-space-character-0x4-in-text-to-output).

HTH!

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly, thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

The top-rated answer didn't work for me, as the given Unicode encoding was rejected. With a slight alteration however, it displayed the desired behaviour:

```
public static String CleanInvalidXmlChars(String text, String replacement) {
    String re = "[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\u0001\\u0000-\\u0010\\uFFFF]";
    return text.replaceAll(re, replacement);
}
```

Comment: This regex accepts all characters in the range of 0x0-0x10. Most of these are not valid in XML.