# Axis2 error: Invalid white space character (0x4) in text to output

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have created a Java client to interact with a SOAP webservice using Axis2 (1.7.6) as code generator. The problem is with some inputs the client is throwing an exception with the message:

`org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid white space character (0x4) in text to output (in xml 1.1, could output as a character entity)`

It seems the serialiser is hitting some chars considered invalid to XML spec. I have seen that problem around but no definitive answer or the fix. I'm not using Spring or any other dependency injection framework, it's a standalone application, so I need to configure the inners of Axis2 by hand.

Any ideas on how to fix/configure the client properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I found this behaviour is due to one default setting of the lib Woodstox (Axis2 dependency), that uses the class `com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler.FailingHandler` as default implementation of the interface `com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler`, used inside `com.ctc.wstx.sw.XmlWriter` and invoked in the serialisation process. This means: when the component hits characters considered invalid to XML, it’ll throw an error.

Woodstox provides another implementation of the interface `com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler`, the one called `com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler.ReplacingHandler` that instead of throwing errors will replace those chars for something else. But how to do that?

The class `com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory` inside Woodstox contains several configurations, one of them being the invalid char handler. Though, it's not configurable by some magic system wide property, instead, by the method `com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory#setProperty`, that takes as arguments one string and one object.

So first, you'll have to extend that factory and set the property *com.ctc.wstx.outputInvalidCharHandler* with an instance of `com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler.ReplacingHandler` that takes as argument the char you want to replace the invalid ones with. Like this:

```
package my.package;

import com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory;
public class MyWstxOutputFatory extends WstxOutputFactory {

    public MyWstxOutputFatory() {
        setProperty(
                com.ctc.wstx.api.WstxOutputProperties.P_OUTPUT_INVALID_CHAR_HANDLER,
                new com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler.ReplacingHandler(' '));
    }
}
```

The second, trickiest and undocumented step is how to register your implementation as the factory Woodstox'll use. You'll have to create a file named `META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory` simply containing the name of your factory, in this case, the string:

```
my.package.MyWstxOutputFatory
```

Place this file in such a way it's included in your project's resulting jar. In my case I placed like: `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory`.

And you're done!